# Cannot SSH to Google Cloud Engine from ubuntu or debian

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform

i try to ssh to my google cloud insance using the local linux. I generated the keys using the docs

ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key -C [USERNAME]

Then putting the pub key to the meta data. But it does not work i allways get a denied connection by Permission denied (publickey). Also the connection with the web shell does not work. With old ssh keys on another machine it works.

Has someone an idea what the problem can be?

Best regards, Alex

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specifically tell it to do otherwise, SSH offers `~/.ssh/id_<type>` (for example, `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) for authentication.

You have created a key at a non-standard location (within ~/.ssh, but with a non-standard file name).

Since public key authentication *in general* works for you, the first thing I would check is that SSH offers the correct key for authentication. You can verify that by running `ssh` with the `-v` switch to turn on one level of verbose (debugging) output. Among the messages, you should see something like:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/you/.ssh/something
```

**Look at which public keys it is offering.** (You may have multiple `Offering ... public key` lines, for different key files.) If it doesn't offer your newly created key, then that key will never be a candidate for authentication.

If your newly created key isn't offered, then try explicitly telling SSH to offer it, by adding the `-i` switch. For example, `ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key -v username@hostname`. Note that SSH will add `.pub` itself to the name where it needs to access the public key, so you give the name for the private key file.

If that works, you can edit your `~/.ssh/config` to tell SSH to offer that key to that host. For example, you could add a block like the following. Make sure to add it above any `Host *` block that you may have.

```
Host hostname
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key
```

Then you should be able to connect using just `ssh hostname`.

See `man 1 ssh` and `man 5 ssh_config` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I think id did it like this. Here is a log, maybe there is someting wrong but i can not identify it.

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ccc.ccc.cc [aaa.aaa.aaa.aa] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to sdev.meilon.de:22 as 'foo'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:D8f511w+xDWBS2z8E212LT369D3og2J4CYRsmE1ETwM
debug1: Host 'sdev.meilon.de' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/foo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: foo@foo-x1
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/foo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/foo/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/foo/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: This log is from the connect with ssh user@target with no other parameter. if i use the special ident file it is the same. it seems that the keys are not compatible with the one that the coud server accepts. with my other pc with ubuntu on it runs perfect.

Comment: i found an error on the google compute engines log:
Jul 13 13:00:30 foo accounts-from-metadata: WARNING error while trying to update accounts: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>